# Negative value of System.nanotime()

Tags: java, loops

can anyone help with my problem? In my game loop for game refreshing and redrawing, sometimes variable "wait" returned negative value. How its possible?

```
while(running) {
        start = System.nanoTime();

        update();
        draw();
        drawToScreen();

        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        wait = targetTime - (elapsed / 1000000);

        try {
            System.out.println(wait);
            Thread.sleep(wait);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is `targetTime`? What is `wait`?

Comment: Can't `elapsed` time be greater than `targetTime`? It would suggest that the amount of time it took to perform the update and repaint took longer than your desired `targetTimer`, perhaps you should the `wait` on those occasions

Comment: Have you considered using a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of writing your own?

Comment: Note that instead of doing your arithmetic this way, you can use `TimeUnit`; it has a `.sleep()` method

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
> wait = targetTime - (elapsed / 1000000);
> ```

1. `wait` is not the value of `System.nanotime()`; wait being negative just means `targetTime - (elapsed / 1000000)` is negative
2. nano = 1 billionth = 1/1000000000 so if targetTime is in seconds you probably don't want `1000000`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the elapsed time is greater than the refresh interval (targetTime). In this case, check if the elapsed is +ve, and sleep only then.